# Unable to Activate Persistent Ignite Cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

We are trying to use control.sh to activate out Ignite cluster which is running in Kubernetes and has native persistence as described [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script), however we are getting to error below.

We have also tried activating the cluster via the post install of the auto deployment but are getting the same error.

```
lifecycle:
    postStart:
        exec:
            command:
              - >-
                /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --set-state ACTIVE
                 --yes
```

Error:

```
/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --set-state ACTIVE
failed - error: command '/bin/sh -c /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --set-state ACTIVE' exited with 2: , message: "JVM_OPTS environment variable is set, but will not be used. To pass JVM options use CONTROL_JVM_OPTS
JVM_OPTS=-DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=false -DIGNITE_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=false -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx4g -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -server -Xms4g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
Control utility [ver. 2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d]2021 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
User: root
Time: 2022-05-31T18:56:38.690
Connection to cluster failed. Latest topology update failed.
Command [SET-STATE] finished with code: 2
Control utility has completed execution at: 2022-05-31T18:56:41.859
Execution time: 3169 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating the cluster relates to the lifecycle of the *cluster* rather than an individual pod, do you don't want to add it to the pod.

Instead, it's a "manual" process once all your nodes/pods are up. [I wrote about it here](https://medium.com/@sdarlington/activating-an-apache-ignite-cluster-on-kubernetes-afbed40c7e53).

In short, either run exec:

```
kubectl exec -it ignite-0 --namespace=ignite -- /opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/bin/control.sh --activate
```

Or create a Kubernetes job.

Comment: This got us on the right path but a few minor tweaks were needed.  We needed to open the control port (11211), create ignite as a service.  We could then specify the ignite service and the port number for the job to activate the cluster.